# DiD-estimate using frequency weighting

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

I´m doing a regression using Dfference-in-Difference (DiD) and frequency weighting (FW) by population. When adding FW my number of observations decrease. Why?

Comment: Your number of observation cannot decrease if you use the same sample. Do you mean "degrees of freedom" decreases?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit over due but I am thinking about a similar problem currently. My educated guess is that if you weight all your regressands and regressors the following might happen:

Let us consider the indicator which indicates whether your observation is part of the treatment group or not. If you weight this indicator with the inverse frequency, you might and up with more than two possible values. If you apply a within transformation or least squary dummy variable approach, you will end up with more groups than two. This is decreasing your degrees of freedom.

But it should not decrease your number of observations.